# finding frequent patterns with pyfpgrowth

Tags: python, data-mining

I am trying to **find frequent patterns** with **pyfpgrowth** library and 
**pandas**, first i created a dataframe with one column,each row is a transaction here is  the code:

```
import pyfpgrowth
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv("itemsets1.csv")
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data.columns = ['itemsets']
data
```

output:
[image]

```
patterns = pyfpgrowth.find_frequent_patterns(data['itemsets'],6)
patterns
```

output:

```
{(' ',): 6, (' ', '1'): 8, ('1',): 9, ('1', '8'): 6, ('8',): 6}
```

actually i have two problems here the first is that the algorithm takes space as an item which is wrong,the second is in the frequence of items for example the item one '1' appears only once, but in the output it shows 9 also wrong, need some help please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note** : I have changed your dataset a bit

**Answer to 1st Question:** The algorithm takes a list as input. In your case, the algo has split each char into a separate value of a list, i.e [5,1, ,2,8, ,2,7]

**Answer to 2nd Question:** You are right in saying that 1 occurs once but as you can see from above example, 1 occurs many times due to wrong split.

Now doing it the right way:

First of all, you need to split each string in itemsets into a list:

```
data['itemsets'] = data.itemsets.apply(lambda x: x.split(' '))
```

The Output:

[image]

Next, the second argument in "**find_frequent_patterns**" is the support level. That means the minimum number of times an item (or a group of items) should occur in all transactions combined. You have entered 6. There is no item that occurs 6 times in your dataset. Let us choose 2.

```
patterns = pyfpgrowth.find_frequent_patterns(data['itemsets'],2)
```

The Output:

> {('10',): 4, ('10', '8'): 2, ('51',): 2, ('8', '81'): 2, ('81',): 4}

In the above output, ***('10','8'):2*** means that 10 and 8 together occur two times in the whole dataset.

Moving a step forward, we can use "generate_association_rules" to generate rules based on a cutoff value. For example:

```
rules = pyfpgrowth.generate_association_rules(patterns, .5)
```

The Output:

> {('10',): (('8',), 0.5), ('81',): (('8',), 0.5)}

It means that 10 and 8 occur together in 50% of all transactions of 10 in the whole dataset (which is 4)

Comment: Hi, can you please explain the rule formation output more elaborately?

Answer (score 1):

You did not prepare the data correctly.

Since in Python a string is a list of characters, you find frequent character sets.

For example, "51" contains the character '1'.

Prepare your data correctly.

Comment: how to do that, split the row for example ??

Comment: Yes. You probably want to split rows on whitespace. maybe also convert the data into integers.